# How to display a string value taken from a resultset variable onto HTML?

Tags: html, string, jsp, exception, resultset

I am trying to print a string which I took from my database and saved it in resultset variable. But when I try to execute it always shows an exception

```
try{
rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from users where user_id='"+username+"'");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}   
%>
<html>
<body style="background-color:powderblue">
<%=username%>'s profile<br>
Username : <%=rs.getString("user_id")%><br>
Gender : <%=rs.getString("g")%><br>
Password : <%=rs.getString("user_password")%><br>
First Name : <%=rs.getString("f_name")%><br>
Last Name : <%=rs.getString("l_name")%><br>
</body>
</html>
```

The error message I get is

```
Type Exception Report
Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/myprofile.jsp] at line [26]
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/myprofile.jsp] at line [26]
23: <html>
24: <body style="background-color:powderblue">
25: <%=username%>'s profile<br>
26: <%=rs.getString("user_id")%>
27: </body>
28: </html>
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.myprofile_jsp._jspService(myprofile_jsp.java:155)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Please add the root cause of the exception (all of the stacktrace).

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `if (rs.next()) {}` or `while (rs.next()) {}`.

```
<%
if (rs.next()) {
%>
    Username : <%=rs.getString("user_id")%><br>
    Gender : <%=rs.getString("g")%><br>
    Password : <%=rs.getString("user_password")%><br>
    First Name : <%=rs.getString("f_name")%><br>
    Last Name : <%=rs.getString("l_name")%><br>
<%
}
%>
```

Comment: Please click "accept" link and close this question.